# Spring Data REST - Spring still calls fndById despite my providing a custom entity lookup

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

I've an almost identical use case to the example given at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/#_customizing_item_resource_uris

I've registered a custom entity lookup and it works great - until the username doesn't exist; it then falls back to `findById(int)` at which point it throws a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` as it tries to convert the `String` into an `int`.

Is there a way to disable the fallback? I don't need or want to access the entity by it's internal id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug. I've filed and fixed [DATAREST-1261](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-1261) for you.

Comment: That's fixed. Feel free to give the snapshots a try.

Comment: Thanks for responding and fixing this so quickly - the snapshot build works like a dream.